# How Can I Create Multiple Files of Random Data?

Tags: macos, file, random

I've been using `dd if=/dev/random of=<file_name> bs=XX count=XX` to create single files of random data.  But I wondered how I could create multiple files at once.  Say 5, 10, or 80,000.  I need to do some bandwidth testing and need unique data.  The above code works great for 1 or 2 files.  My programming (Python) and terminal skill are still very minimal.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

man split.

[Split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) splits a file or stdin to multiple files based on file size or number of lines. It doesn't happen "at once" or in parallel though.

`dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=10 | split -b 2` produces 5 files xaa,xab..xae each consisting of 2 bytes.

Comment: Excellent.  I'm not overly fond of having to figure how many bytes I need the files split into, but it works well enough.  If there's a better argument to pass that'd be great since I'm splitting files that are up to hundreds of GB in size.  But I'll manage if there aren't.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `GNU Parallel` for this. The command line syntax is very intuitive and concise and it does all your work in parallel, i.e. FAST, and uses all those lovely CPU cores in your Mac.

So, to create 8 files in parallel, each of 100MB, you would type this in the Terminal:

```
$ parallel dd if=/dev/random of=random-{} bs=1000000 count=100 ::: {0..7}
```

and you will end up with these 8 files just 60 seconds later:

```
$ ls -l random-*

-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  100000000 19 Dec 11:52 random-0
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  100000000 19 Dec 11:52 random-1
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  100000000 19 Dec 11:52 random-2
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  100000000 19 Dec 11:52 random-3
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  100000000 19 Dec 11:52 random-4
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  100000000 19 Dec 11:52 random-5
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  100000000 19 Dec 11:52 random-6
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  100000000 19 Dec 11:52 random-7
```

Or, if you wanted one file of 1kB, two files of 64kB, one file of 32kB and one of 128kB, you would do this:

```
$ parallel dd if=/dev/random of=random-{%} bs=1024 count={1} ::: 1 64 64 32 128
```

which will give you this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff  131072 19 Dec 12:10 random-5
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff   32768 19 Dec 12:10 random-4
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff   65536 19 Dec 12:10 random-3
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff   65536 19 Dec 12:10 random-2
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    1024 19 Dec 12:10 random-1
```

The easiest way, to my mind, of installing `parallel` on OSX is to get `homebrew` from [the homebrew website](http://brew.sh), then all you do is:

```
brew install parallel
```