# How to create multiple files with random data with bash

Tags: macos, bash, shell, scripting

How do I create multiple files (More than 20k,  I need these files to run a test for syncying) with random data in OS X? I used a previously answered question ([How Can I Create Multiple Files of Random Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000732/os-x-how-can-i-create-multiple-files-of-random-data)) that suggested to use something like

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=40000 | split -b 2
```

But using that gives me an error saying too many files.Any other way I can create a loop that will create files with any random data?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it with a shell `for` loop:

```
for i in {1..20000}; do dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=1 of=file$i; done
```

Adjust `count` and `bs` as necessary to make files of the size you care about.  Note that I changed to `/dev/urandom` to prevent blocking.

You can add some `>/dev/null 2>&1` to quiet it down, too.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! I am still unsure what count means in this script? (I am new to scripting)

Comment: `count` is an argument to `dd`.  [`man dd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dd.1.html) for more.

Comment: ... specifically, `count=1` will give you one block of output, and `bs=1` will give you a block size of one - so a single byte each time, rather than 2 bytes in your example.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you have any file naming requirements, but perhaps this:

```
for x in {1..20000}; do
  dd if=/dev/random of=test$x.dat bs=10000 count=4
done
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason your approach doesn't work is that the default suffix for `split` (2 alphabetic characters) isn't a big enough namespace for twenty thousand files. If you add a couple of options:

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=40000 | split -b 2 -d -a 5
```

(where `-d` means "use digits, not alphabetic characters, for the suffix" and `-a 5` means "use suffixes of length 5"), it ought to work fine - I tested it with `/dev/urandom` (for speed) on a GNU/Linux machine without problems.

Note that this is much faster than the for-loop approach of the other answers (2.5 seconds versus 43 seconds for Carl Norum's answer on my machine).

Comment: The "-d" option is not available on macOS (10.13.6). Without it, the command example works, though then names such as "xaaaaa", "xaaaab" etc. are generated.